# How to change a entry widgets border color in Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, border, tkinter-entry

I am working on a program that has a entry widget. And when the user clicks a button and that entry widget is empty then the program will change the border color of it to red. But when I try the border just stays the same color, which is black.

Here is the code:

```
self.timeField = Entry(self.mfr, width=40, relief=SOLID, highlightbackground="red", highlightcolor="red")
self.timeField.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)
```

Then in the if statement that checks if it is empty has this to change it to red but it does not seem to work:

```
self.timeField.config(highlightbackground="red")
self.timeField.config(highlightcolor="red")
```

Can someone explain to me why this is not working, what I am doing wrong, and a way to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Update:
Here is the rest of the code as requested:

```
def start(self):
    waitTime = self.timeField.get()
    password = self.passField.get()

    cTime = str(self.tVers.get())
    self.cTime = cTime

    if waitTime.strip() != "":
        if password.strip() != "":
            if waitTime.isdigit():
                if self.cTime == "Secs":
                    waitTime = int(waitTime)
                elif self.timeVer == "Mins":
                    waitTime = int(waitTime) * 60
                else:
                    waitTime = int(waitTime) * 3600

                self.password = password

                root.withdraw()
                time.sleep(float(waitTime))
                root.deiconify()
                root.overrideredirect(True)
                root.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()))

                self.tfr.destroy()
                self.mfr.destroy()
                self.bfr.destroy()

                self.create_lockScreen()
            else:
                self.timeField.configure(highlightcolor="red")
        else:
            self.passFields.configure(highlightcolor="red")
    else:
        self.timeField.config(highlightbackground="red", highlightcolor="red")
```

Comment: Maybe the if statement is never executing. How large is your code? Can you post the whole thing?

Comment: @Kevin The statement is executing because I had it say print after the config part and it printed. So it has to be something else.

Comment: You might have missed the second half of my previous comment, since I edited it in rather late. How large is your code? Can you post the whole thing?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. When I said the "whole thing", I meant "the entire program" rather than "the entire function". I would like to be able to copy and paste your code and run it, and see the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Addressing the issue with highlightthickness

The code you've given should work, though you may be bumping up against platform implementation (ie: windows may not treat the highlightthickness the same as other platforms)

Here's a program that should work, though I haven't tested it on windows 7:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.entry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Validate", command=self.validate)
        self.entry.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        self.button.pack(side="bottom")

        self.validate() # initialize the border

    def validate(self):
        data = self.entry.get()
        if len(data) == 0:
            self.entry.configure(highlightbackground="red", highlightcolor="red")
        else:
            self.entry.configure(highlightbackground="blue", highlightcolor="blue")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

#### Using a frame to simulate a border

Another solution is to create a border with a frame that is just slightly larger than the button. Here's a quick example. Its not really production ready, but it illustrates the point:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.entry = CustomEntry(self)
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Validate", command=self.validate)
        self.entry.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        self.button.pack(side="bottom")

        self.validate() # initialize the border

    def validate(self):
        data = self.entry.get()
        if len(data) == 0:
            self.entry.set_border_color("red")
        else:
            self.entry.set_border_color("blue")

class CustomEntry(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.entry.pack(fill="both", expand=2, padx=2, pady=2)

        self.get = self.entry.get
        self.insert = self.entry.insert

    def set_border_color(self, color):
        self.configure(background=color)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I tried the self.entry.configure(highlightbackground="red", highlightcolor="red") in my code and it did not work. I posted the rest of the code so that you can see if anything is wrong with it.

Comment: @BurningCode: you ran it exactly as-is, without changing anything? What platform are you running this on?

Comment: Yes I ran it exactly as it is. I am running windows 7 with Python 2.7.9

Comment: The meaning of 'focus hightlight' may well depend on the system.  I ran on Win 7, 3.4.  If I type something, tab to the button and back to the entry, the text gets a blue background and typing anything erases the blued text and replaces it with the character typed.  Moving focus back with a mouse click does not blue the text but just adds the cursor, and any key hit is appended.

Comment: @BurningCode: nope. Probably is a limitation or bug on windows

Comment: @BryanOakley Is there another way I could make it look like the border turned red?

Comment: @BurningCode: yes, you can put a frame behind the button and make it just a couple of pixels wider and taller than the button.

Comment: @BryanOakley Thanks the using the Frame as a border worked. Can you change your answer to where you use a Frame as a border so I can accept it? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Altough it is an old question i stumbled upon the same problem on windows 10 and there is meanwhile a fairly simple solution.

In addition to setting the highlightbackground and color you have to change the highlightthickness to something greater zero.
[Bryan Oekley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7432/bryan-oakley) mentioned it in the heading of his answer but i couldnt find it in his code so here is a little code snippet.

```
self.entry = tk.Entry(self, highlightthickness=2)
self.entry.configure(highlightbackground="red", highlightcolor="red")
```

(this should maybe be a comment on Bryans Answer)